# LVM mirrored reads goes to one drive instead of both

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, raid, lvm

I've set up LVM mirror on two HDDs. The mirror works (and even has proven it's efficiency when drives failed two times).

The problem is that all read operations goes to only one HDD, I see it with iostat. I even run multi-threaded read tests with fio tool to double-check this.

As I know, with read ops on mirror, all IO should go to both drives with some policy (round-robin is most obvious), improvind read performance by doing this.

So the question is: can linux's (ubuntu's) LVM place mirrored read ops to both physical drives, and, if it can, how can I tell LVM to do this?

I have Ubunty 14.04 by now, and ready to give detailed information if needed.